# MySQL PDO Connection Security

Tags: mysql, security, mariadb

Up until this point I have never had to setup users that can access my MySQL (actually MariaDB) instance from anything other than *localhost*.  However, I now need to setup a *slave* that will access the database on the *master* on a private network.  The only issue is that the network in question is not really *that private* given the fact that the two servers are VMs and the private network is shared by all the machines at that location (potentially I imagine this is 100s or even 1000s).  It is unclear to me what if anything I need to do to secure access to the database from the private network.

Is a PDO connection string bearing the form

```
new PDO("mysql:host=masterprivateip;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8",
"slaveuser",'slaveuser@slaveprivateip',...
```

sufficiently secure if I use strong passwords or do I need to take other measures to ensure the integrity of the database? I should mention that in any case the slaveuser will only have SELECT grants on the database in question.

Comment: What do you mean by "secure"?  Are you trying to prevent eavesdroppers from being able to authenticate their own sessions, prevent them from observing requests/responses, prevent them from altering requests/responses, or prevent them from performing man-in-the-middle attacks?

Comment: MySQL/MariaDB supports SSL secured, encrypted connections. If you're serious about security, you will want to look into that.

Comment: Everything that goes into my database is encrypted and I never trust any data coming to the server without subjecting it to exhaustive verification so I am not concerned about anyone eavesdroppping on requests (they will make no sense anyway). Same applies to MIMA and efforts at modifying req/reps - any tampering will trigger a failure in my verification routines. Authenticate sessions - I am not sure how that might happen. If I ask the question it is because it is not clear to me that I have an issue to deal with here. I lack the experience to establish what the security issues could be here.